# Perl's Regexp Error

Tags: regex, perl

I have this code:

```
sub makeNonVerbatimSubstitutions {
    my $self = shift;
    my $input = shift;
    $input =~ s/^(\S.*)$/(?{$self -> makeOneNonVerbatimSubstitution ($&)}))/mge;
    return $input;
}
```

But Perl doesn't like line with regexp:

```
Use of ?PATTERN? without explicit operator is deprecated at RTFWriter.pm line 146.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the extended pattern for code in the right hand side of a substitution, which as far as I know does not work. And is not needed either. Plus you are trying to evaluate it with the `/e` modifier. What you need is only:

```
$input =~ s/^(\S.*)$/$self->makeOneNonVerbatimSubstitution ($&)/mge;
```

Though of course you are aware that with the `/m` modifier, this also applies the substitution inside the string, should it find a newline that can act as "line break".

And also, such long subroutine names, with names that look identical is not something I would opt for. If you need to clarify a subroutines functionality, use a comment instead.

Note that as toolic says, if you `use diagnostics`, it will explain your error in more detail. This is what I got when I ran similar code:

```
Use of ?PATTERN? without explicit operator is deprecated at -e line 1 (#1)
    (D deprecated) You have written something like ?\w?, for a regular
    expression that matches only once.  Starting this term directly with
    the question mark delimiter is now deprecated, so that the question mark
    will be available for use in new operators in the future.  Write m?\w?
    instead, explicitly using the m operator: the question mark delimiter
    still invokes match-once behaviour.

Search pattern not terminated or ternary operator parsed as search pattern at
        -e line 1 (#2)
    (F) The lexer couldn't find the final delimiter of a ?PATTERN?
    construct.

    The question mark is also used as part of the ternary operator (as in
    foo ? 0 : 1) leading to some ambiguous constructions being wrongly
    parsed.  One way to disambiguate the parsing is to put parentheses around
    the conditional expression, i.e. (foo) ? 0 : 1.
```

Which basically means that it thought you started a `? ... ?` pattern, which is deprecated, and also, it could not find the closing questionmark `?`. What this means is that `(?...` was not recognized by your parser, because it is not valid here.

Answer (score 1):

You've got one more parenthesis than needed in the line. Instead of:

```
$input =~ s/^(\S.*)$/(?{$self -> makeOneNonVerbatimSubstitution ($&)}))/mge;
```

it should read:

```
$input =~ s/^(\S.*)$/(?{$self -> makeOneNonVerbatimSubstitution ($&)})/mge;
```

(note that I removed the last parenthesis).